# Plot matrix with GNUplot. Slow

Tags: performance, matrix, gnuplot

I am using GNUplot for plotting a small matrix.
The matrix is 100x100 by size. e.g.

```
1.23212 2.43123 -1.24312 ......
-4.23123 2.00458 5.60234 ......
......
```

The data is not neatly stored in the file.
So from C++ point of view, due to the lack of length per data, there is no way to load a whole number, but it has to check when the number is loading. I guess this should be the reason of the slow plotting speed.

Now I have 3 questions:

**Q1**: Is loading the bottle neck?

**Q2**: If I can make the data file neatly stored. e.g.

```
 1.23212  2.43123 -1.24312 ......
-4.23123  2.00458  5.60234 ......
......
```

Does the plotting speed get any improvement? (Maybe GNUplot can check what the pattern is. Thus improve the loading speed. Not sure.)

**Q3**: Any other options that I can set to make it faster?

**Edit**

I tried these:

```
-3.07826e-21 -2.63821e-20 -1.05205e-19 -3.25317e-19 -9.1551e-19
```

when outputting used `setw` to make sure there they are aligned. But I think I still need to tell GNUplot to load 13 characters at one time, then perform `strtod`.
I would guess, in order to fit a general case, where there is no information for the length of the number, it is safe to do it digit by digit until it there is a space.

Comment: quite unlikely adding spaces will improve performance, but why dont you try it..?

Comment: Have you tried Q2? What was the result? How are you plotting the matrix with gnuplot?